# REACTJS: Cómo mantengo el contexto de router aunque mis componentes tengan un render separado

Tags: reactjs, webforms

Estamos migrando una Aplicativo antiguo pero necesito hacer el render de algunos componentes por separado, por ejemplo el menú hay que renderizarlo en cierto Div particular y el contenido según la ruta va en otro Div, esto porque el aplicativo está actualmente en ASP.NET WEBFORM de .NET FRAMEWORK. Tecnologías un poco antiguas.
[image: Estructura de ruteo con React Router]

El problema que tengo es porque ese que resalto es el menú pero está fuera del contexto del router. ya he intentado agregarlo dentro pero por el tema de que hago ReactDom.Render me genera errores.

La versión de REACT es la 17

Comment: Quizas te sería de ayuda revisar la documentación de React Portals: https://es.react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, el problema esta interesante pero recomiendo que nos des mas detalles de lo que estas tratando de hacer actualizando la pregunta